# Heap corruption when making two bytes into a short. C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dealloc, heap-corruption

I am developing a program in C++ and encounter this error when I run this code:

```
short readshort() {
    short val=0;
    (&val)[1]=data.front(); data.pop_front();
    (&val)[0]=data.front(); data.pop_front();
    return val;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'val' was corrupted.
```

I should mention now, that "data" is defined with std::list data;

I think I know what is the problem, but I cannot think of an easy solution. I think this error is cause by the "val" being stored in the stack, and not as a pointer. When I try to access the data pointer by "val" I get this error.

The solution I thought about was allocating "val" like this:

```
short readshort() {
    short* val=new short;
    val[1]=data.front(); data.pop_front();
    val[0]=data.front(); data.pop_front();
    return *val;
}
```

But I can't see a way to delete "val" once I have returned it without having to delete it outside the function every time.
Is there a way this can be done in C++ wihtout a memory leak? I havn't seen anyone split a variable type (e.g. short) into bytes using "(&val)[1]" before, and wondered if this was because it gave rise to a number of problems, or is it just not a known method?

Coming back to the real question, how can I make these two bytes into short (or large data type)? And is there a better way of doing this than what I have tried?

One last thing, I know that java has an automatic garbage collector that cleans up memory leaks automatically. Does C++ offer the same kind of device? I heard somthing about Smart Pointers, but I don't know what they are ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is safe and simple:

```
int16_t readshort()
{
    union { int16_t s; char val[2]; } u;
    u.val[1]=data.front(); data.pop_front();
    u.val[0]=data.front(); data.pop_front();
    return *(int16_t*)u.val;
}
```

Comment: Is that really safe?  What if that array ends up being not 16-bit aligned?  Maybe it has to be - I'm not a C++ expert, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Carl: Maybe it isn't safe for automatic variables. Never met a system where it wasn't. Others: "For arrays of  char and
unsigned  char, the difference between the result of the new-expression and the address returned by the
allocation function shall be an integral multiple of the strictest fundamental alignment requirement (3.11) of
any object type whose size is no greater than the size of the array being created. [ Note: this constraint on array allocation overhead permits the common idiom of allocating
character arrays into which objects of other types will later be placed.  — end note ]"

Comment: @Carl: Updated to guarantee alignment.

Answer (score 1):

`(&val)[1]=data.front()` an error by doing `(&val)[1]` you are writing next memory location to `val` that is not defined.

`(&val)[i]` means `*(&val + i )`
`(&val)[0]` means `*(&val + 0 )` = `*(&val)` this fine
`(&val)[1]` means `*(&val + 1 )` =  But this is error because your declaration is `short val` so we can access only val location.

```
+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+---+----+ 
|val      |        |
+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+---+---+----+  
 201   202  203 204 205 206  207   208 209 210  211
  ^           ^ 
   |          |
 &val         (&val + 1) 
              its not defined.
```

you could use tyoecase  like @Carl Norum suggested. I am just writing second form to do this.

```
char *ptr = (char*)&val;

ptr[0]=data.front()
ptr[1]=data.front()
```

But if your need `val` as short and wanted to access individual bytes. I would like to suggest `union`:

```
union Data{
 short val;
 char ch1;
 char ch2;
};

union Data d; 

d.ch1 = data.front()
d.ch2 = data.front()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your pointer to char*.

```
((char *)(&val))[1]=data.front();
((char *)(&val))[0]=data.front();
```

I think in your case: (&val)[1]=data.front(); you write data to second short. As result you get error.

Answer (score 0):

`(&val)[1]` accesses memory you don't have allocated.  Bam - undefined behaviour.  Both of your examples have the same problem.

If you want to split bytes like that, you need to use `char` pointers to access the individual bytes:

```
short readshort() {
    short val=0;
    ((char *)&val)[1]=data.front(); data.pop_front();
    ((char *)&val)[0]=data.front(); data.pop_front();
    return val;
}
```

This code is really pretty ugly, though.  Why not just:

```
short readshort() {
    short val=0;
    val  = data.front() << 8; data.pop_front();
    val |= data.front() << 0; data.pop_front();
    return val;
}
```

Depending on endianness, you may need to swap the positions of the `8` and `0` there.